# Converting true color(32 bit) HBITMAP into monochrome bitmap (e.g 1 bit) in Winapi

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi, win32gui

Hello I am trying to convert HBITMAP into a monochrome bitmap which will use 1 bit. The issue is when I am converting the image is not the monochrome version of original bitmap. Also I do not want to use any additional library. Here I am sending the code.

```
HBITMAP ConvertToMonochromeBitmap(HBITMAP hBmp) {
    BITMAP bmp;
    GetObject(hBmp, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmp);

    // Truecolor bmi
    BITMAPINFO bmiTrueColor = { 0 };
    bmiTrueColor.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmiTrueColor.bmiHeader.biWidth = bmp.bmWidth;
    bmiTrueColor.bmiHeader.biHeight = -bmp.bmHeight;
    bmiTrueColor.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bmiTrueColor.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32;
    bmiTrueColor.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

    // Getting TrueColor bitmap bits
    BYTE* pBitmapBits = new BYTE[bmp.bmWidth * bmp.bmHeight * 4];
    GetDIBits(GetDC(NULL), hBmp, 0, bmp.bmHeight, pBitmapBits, &bmiTrueColor, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    // Create BYTE* array for Monochrome bitmap
    BYTE* pMonochromeData = new BYTE[bmp.bmWidth * bmp.bmHeight / 8];
    memset(pMonochromeData, 0, bmp.bmWidth * bmp.bmHeight / 8);

    for (int i = 0; i < bmp.bmWidth * bmp.bmHeight; i++) {
        int blue = pBitmapBits[i * 4];
        int green = pBitmapBits[i * 4 + 1];
        int red = pBitmapBits[i * 4 + 2];
        int grayscale = (red + green + blue) / 3;

        // Calculate the index in the monochrome bitmap.
        int monochromeIndex = i / 8;

        // Calculate the bit position within the byte.
        int bitOffset = 7 - (i % 8);

        // Set the corresponding bit in the monochrome bitmap.
        if (grayscale < 128) {
            // Set bit to 1 if color is black
            pMonochromeData[monochromeIndex] |= (1 << bitOffset);
        }
        else {
            // Set bit to 0 if color is not black
            pMonochromeData[monochromeIndex] &= ~(1 << bitOffset);
        }
    }

    BITMAPINFO bmi = { 0 };
    bmi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bmi.bmiHeader.biWidth = bmp.bmWidth;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -bmp.bmHeight;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 1;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bmi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = bmp.bmWidth * bmp.bmHeight / 8;

    HBITMAP newBitmap = CreateDIBitmap(GetDC(NULL), &bmi.bmiHeader, CBM_INIT, pMonochromeData, &bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    delete[] pMonochromeData;
    delete[] pBitmapBits;

    return newBitmap;
}
```

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you want a 1 bit (two colour bitmap)? If so your best bet is to convert the original colour image down to an 8 bit monochrome image first and then make a histogram of all the byte values in it.  Then examine the histogram and set your threshold so that approximately half of the cells are the same colour (or choose where to split it by some other heuristic). BTW Luminance y = 0.3*r + 0.59*g + 0.11*b 
 (approx). You must also define a colour LUT with two entries see BMP format [Color table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Color_table).

Comment: Please see [ask].

Comment: @MartinBrown Well there is still (ordered) dithering which will arguably have better results.. I haven't used that in 30 years though. E.g. https://observablehq.com/@jobleonard/ordered-error-diffusion-dithering/

Comment: If by "I do not want to use any additional library", you mean just work with Windows, you can use WIC ("Windows Imaging Component" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/-wic-lh) instead of GDI that has source (for any bitmap format supported by Windows) to monochrome (1bpp) conversion built-in (and you can also use an error diffusion algorithm). Otherwise you current algorithm doesn't work at all (+ buffer overrun issue).